# width and height of frame are different in initWithFrame and drawRect

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

**GOAL**: To customize the background view of cell.

Here is what I am doing

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell   =   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 80)];

    cell.backgroundColor=   [UIColor purpleColor];

    return cell;
}
```

CustomCellBackground.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"frame.x = %f",frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"frame.y = %f",frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"frame.width = %f",frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"frame.height = %f",frame.size.height);
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor    =   [UIColor purpleColor];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
NSLog(@"frame.x = %f",self.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@"frame.y = %f",self.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"frame.width = %f",self.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"frame.height = %f",self.frame.size.height);


}
```

In CustomCellBacground, I am printing out the size of frame in initWithFrame and drawRect method and what Iam getting is

```
    IN INITWITHFRAME
frame.x = 0.000000
frame.y = 0.000000
frame.width = 200.000000
frame.height = 80.000000

    IN DRAWRECT

//Updated as requested
rect.x = 0.000000
rect.y = 0.000000
rect.width = 302.000000
rect.height = 201.000000

frame.x = 9.000000
frame.y = 0.000000
frame.width = 302.000000
frame.height = 201.000000
```

QUESTION : why the size of frame in `drawRect()` has been changed recently. Should these values stay as same as in `initWithFrame`

Comment: What does the size in rect coming in with your drawrect routine return / output?

Comment: Frame defines view's position in relation to superviews coordinates. Since your coordinates in drawrect are to the right of `CGPointZero` I'd assume that once the view has been added to the cell, it's been moved. Also - don't forget that cells have `contentView` which might be affecting the position of your background view.

Comment: @trumpetlicks :please see the update in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell resizes its `backgroundView` to fill the cell.  The frame you pass to `initWithFrame:` is irrelevant.